# How can I have RecyclerView children ignore relative positioning?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am experimenting with a RecyclerView and it currently displays four CardViews vertically on the screen. Using an adapter, I am able to resize each CardView's height equally in the space given.

What I'm trying to accomplish:

On click, I would like the selected RecyclerView child to expand to fullscreen. Currently, I can programmatically set the height and expand the selected CardView dimensions, but the other CardViews after it are pushed down off-screen. How can I have all the selected CardView positioning become absolute, and lock the other views positions and expand "over" them? Is this the proper approach, or should I be looking into shared-element transitions or something else?

Side-ask: Is there a way to control all top/left positioning of RecyclerView children in an adapter?

Comment: Something like this? https://developer.android.com/training/animation/zoom

Comment: I think shared element transition is better option.

Comment: @AmratSingh got the point. The expand detail view should be another activity or fragment, and `SharedElementTransition` is used to make the smooth expand animation

Comment: @TamHuynh Yeah, Right.

Answer (score 1):

The comments above seem to be correct - after looking into shared transitions, I found numerous examples performing the exact behavior I described. Crediting @AmratSingh since he answered first.

If it helps anyone, here is the one I am following currently: [Michael Scammell - Shared Element Transitions](https://github.com/mikescamell/shared-element-transitions)

This one in particular: [Shared element transitions within a RecyclerView](https://github.com/mikescamell/shared-element-transitions/tree/master/app/src/main/java/com/mikescamell/sharedelementtransitions/recycler_view)

Comment: Following up: I ended up resorting to creating a card expansion animation class that implemented multiple value animators to tween the card to full screen dimensions. We had to do this instead of a shared element transition so we could control every aspect of the animation, and for performance since we were loading other assets behind the scenes.